# Event is firing multiple times (Parse.com)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dom-events, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm writing an app in Parse, using the JavaScript framework.  In my view, I have a link with the class 'new-page'.  In the JS code, I have:

```
    events: {
        "click .new-page" : "createPage",
    }
```

createPage is:

```
    createReel: function() {
        var self = this;
        // Get current pagelist
        var pages= new PageList;
        pages.query = new Parse.Query(Page);
        pages.query.equalTo("owner", Parse.User.current());
        pages.query.ascending("order");
        pages.fetch({
            success: function(pagelist) {
                var newPage = new Page;
                newPage .save({
                    success: function(newpage) {
                         // Redirect to page edit
                         new PageEditView();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

First time round, this works fine - the new page is created, and it goes to edit mode for that page.  But if I then go back to the view with the 'Add Page' button and click it again, I get 2 new pages.  If I do it again, I get 4, and so on.

I assume the event is 'building up', so that the more times the button is clicked, the more times the event gets fired.

I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Read up on Backbone zombie views, it sounds like your event is not being removed/unbound properly.

Comment: When you're going back to the view with the button, are you removing the old PageEditView?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I just had a similar issue.

The mistake I made was that I created the view instance again every time I needed it.

That is not how Backbone is ment to work.

Views are (usually) created once. And when their model changes, the are being rendered again.

you seem to be instantiating your view every time the user saves at this line

```
PageEditView();
```

That's when the events stack up.

Instantiate that view once when you start up the page and then render it whenever you update the model for that view.

In native bakbone, event handlers can listen to model changes. Somehow it won't work in the Parse backbone version (or I can't get it to work). So for now, I do that manually with

```
PageEditView.model = model
PageEditView.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you undelegate events before calling the new PageEditView.